# otrs 5 in shared host

Tags: apache, perl, otrs

I would like to install OTRS 5 in a shared hosting environment. I heard, that this is possible but not easy.

Here is what I know so far and what I did:

- Webfolder: **/var/www/html/**
- otrs-5.0.23.tar.gz is extraced to /var/www/html/cgi-bin/
- Also added /var/www/html/otrs-web
- Permissions are set to 755
- Config.pm.dist renamed to Config.pm
- Created a DB an gave the Informations to Config.pm
- Home Path is set to /var/www/html/cgi-bin/
- I imported the three mysql SQL Files to te OTRS DB
- I renamed the Cronjobs
- Links were set ln -s /var/www/html/otrs-web/skins/ /var/www/html/cgi-bin/var/httpd/htdocs/skins
  ln -s /var/www/html/otrs-web/js/ /var/www/html/cgi-bin/var/httpd/htdocs/js

After this, I tried to open http://192.168.0.160/otrs-web in the browser. It gets the index.html a it tries to redirect me to http://192.168.0.160/otrs/index.pl but ends with

```
Not Found

The requested URL /otrs/index.pl was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 192.168.0.160 Port 80
```

The content of the index.html is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/otrs/index.pl" />
    <title>OTRS Redirect</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<!--
index.html - redirect
Copyright (C) 2001-2017 OTRS AG, http://otrs.com/

This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. For details, see
the enclosed file COPYING for license information (AGPL). If you
did not receive this file, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.txt.
-->
```

I have to confess, that I am not into this whole redirection stuff. I gues, this might be the problem. If someone do have an Idea or a link to a nice tutorial, I would be happy :)

Comment: Did you install the Apache config file as the OTRS install guide suggests?

Comment: Hi, as it is a shared web server I do not have access to the apache config. Do you have an idea, how to handle this by editing the .htaccess?